# Got "The process has forked" error in multiprocessing with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, macos, multiprocessing

I have a huge dataframe that I want to split through Multiprocess, do some work and write the results in files. However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug
```

The code is like this:

```
def func(d):
    first = d.iloc[0].id
    _f = open('output_' + str(first) + '.json', 'w')
    options = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
    for index, row in d.iterrows():
        res = dfApply(row, driver, _f) 
        # in this function I use selenium to scrape a website and write some results in the 
        # json file. If the scraping returns True (got result), I delete the row. If not, I 
        # let it there in the dataframe.
        if res:
            d.drop(index, inplace=True)    
    return row
    
            
if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.read_csv('rest.csv', nrows = 100) 
    print('Dataframe size:', df.shape)

    num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    
    chunk_size = int(df.shape[0]/num_processes)
    
    chunks = [df.ix[df.index[i:i + chunk_size]] for i in range(0, df.shape[0], chunk_size)]
    
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)
    
    result = pool.map(func, chunks)
```

Comment: You are on macOS are you?

Comment: Yes, I am. Didn't know it was related. Also run the code in Spyder 4 with anaconda-navigator

Comment: FYi it’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a macOS related warning-error because of the attempted use of forking (default for Python < 3.8) without `exec()` (overwrites process image) as a start method for new processes.

Excerpt from the [bug-tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue33725):

> ... The problem is in higher-level APIs (CoreFoundation, Foundation,
>   AppKit, ...), and appears to be related to using multi-threading in
>   those libraries without spending effort on pre/post fork handlers to
>   ensure that new processes are in a sane state after fork().  In older
>   macOS versions this could result in hard to debug issues, in newer
>   versions APIs seem to guard against this by aborting when the detect
>   that the pid changed.

Switch you start-method for new processes to "spawn" for resolving it:

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")
```

For [Python 3.8+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#multiprocessing) the start-method for macOS is "spawn" by default.

Comment: It doesn't work using pexpect on OSX El Capitan with Python 3.6